# Dask: read sql table from another user

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dask, cx-oracle

I'm using `dask` in Python to read an SQL table from an established connection (I use `cx_Oracle`, `sqlalchemy`). My own tables are readily available, but I don't know how to access the tables from other users which were made available to me.

In SQL itself I would would just reference the table with `other_user.their_table`. However, with `dask`:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd    
example_table = dd.read_sql_table("other_user.their_table", connstr, "idxcolumn")
```

doesn't work ("no such table"). Any ideas how to access these tables?

Comment: Have you tried `dd.read_sql_table("their_table", connstr, "idxcolumn", schema="other_user")`

Comment: thanks, this easy solution did what i wanted :) if you post it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Dask dataframe's read_sql_table method uses the same method from Pandas.  I recommend first trying with Pandas to make sure that that works.  If it doesn't, then I recommend that you resubmit a similar question tagged with the Pandas tag.  They have far more coverage.